# Euler characteristic of a sphere with $n$ holes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces

If I understood correctly, a sphere with a single hole is a torus, and has genus 1. Its Euler characteristic is 0.

If it has two holes, the Euler characteristic is -2. Three holes, -4.

However, I don't know how to generalize for a sphere with $n$ holes. Although it seems somewhat intuitive given the initial results, I couldn't prove it formally... Can anybody help me on that?

Comment: It depends on your definition of the Euler characteristic.

Comment: At any rate, the answer is $2-2g$ where $g$ is the genus.

Comment: But this formula depends on the definition? Didn't know there were more than 1... I use Do Carmo's book on Differential Geometry

Comment: The formula does not depend on the definition, of course, but you asked for a proof.  The proof would, naturally, depend on what definition you use.

Comment: Got it. It is the Euler-Poincare characteristic

Comment: It would help immensely to put the definition in the body of the question.  There are multiple ways to define the EP characteristic.  Do you use the homology version?  The integral version?  The simplicial version?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition I think that suffices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on the previous answer, you know that $\chi(M\#N)=\chi(M)+\chi(N)-\chi(S^2)$ where $M\#N$ is the connected sum. Recognizing that a genus $g$ surface is a genus $g-1$ surface together with a torus, the result follows by an easy induction.